# How would I return this? (MobileSubstrate)

Tags: ios, header, theos, cydia-substrate

I'm looking to mod a game, and I found this function in the dumped headers:

[code]-(void)didCompleteRewardedVideo:(id)video withReward:(int)reward;
[/code]

How would I make it so that reward would return 9999999? Also, there is supposed to be a space in "video withReward". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)didCompleteRewardedVideo:(id)video withReward:(int)reward
{
     %orig(video,9999999);
}
```